# How to POST multiple list of fields data to child model along with parent model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two models Visit(parent model) and VisitAccessories(Child Model). when i Post(VisitAccessories) data only last element of the list get added and record gets created. but others element are ignored.

`models.py`

```
class Visit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, name="name")


class VisitAccessories(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
     accessories_photo = models.FileField(upload_to="accessories/", null=True, blank=True)
     description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
     visit = models.ForeignKey(Visit,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`serializer.py`

```
class VisitAccessoriesSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = VisitAccessories
       exclude = ("visit",)#visit is foregin key to visit model


class ListAccessoriesSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     visit_accessories = VisitAccessoriesSerializers(many=True,source='visitaccessories_set', required=False,)

      class Meta:
         model = VisitAccessories
         exclude = ("visit",) #visit is foregin key to visit model

class VisitSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      visit_accessories = VisitAccessoriesSerializers(many=True, source='visitaccessories_set', required=False)
    class Meta:
       model = Visit
       fields = ('__all__')
```

`views.py`

```
    def post(self, request):
       serializer = VisitSerializers(data=request.data)
       accessories_serializer = ListAccessoriesSerializers(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError) and accessories_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
           visit_obj = serializer.save() # Visit Created
           accessories_serializer.save(visit=visit_obj) # VisitAccessories
           return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       return Response(serializer.error_messages, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

variable `accessories_serializer` data i get is

```
ListAccessoriesSerializers(data=<QueryDict: {'name': ['Axxx'], 'gender': ['M'], 'mobile': ['900000'], 'visit_time': ['2019-06-04T17:00:56.901634+05:30'], 'to_meet': ['15'], 'title': ['pppp', 'ttttttt', 'vvvvv'], 'accessories_photo': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Syndicate_Bank.svg.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: maruti-suzuki-reuters-small.jpg (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: rupee11.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>):
```

from title list only `vvvvv`(last element) 1 record gets created. instead of 3 Records

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class VisitSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    visit_accessories = VisitAccessoriesSerializers(many=True, source='visitaccessories_set', required=False)

    class Meta:
       model = Visit
       fields = ('__all__')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        accessories_data = validated_data.pop('visit_accessories') # pop the nested data
        serializer = VisitSerializers(data=validated_data)
        instance = super().create(validated_data) # create base object

        accessories_serializer = ListAccessoriesSerializers(many=True,
            context={'request': request, 'visit_id': instance.id}
        )
        accessories_serializer.create(accessories_data) # create nested objects
        return instance
```

Comment: got this `KeyError: 'visit_accessories'`

Comment: I am not getting nested data i have given format i get for `ListAccessoriesSerializers` above

Comment: you need to add many=True in your view.py


   `accessories_serializer = ListAccessoriesSerializers(data=request.data, many=True)`

or 

add `visit_accessories`   inside  `fields = ('__all__')`

Comment: also request value is `None`

Comment: pass `context={'request': request}` in your serializer.

Comment: In postman I am passing 'title' and value  without  visit_accessories field